# How to show AVG value in Matrix Widget along with Total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using Matrix Widget in Power BI where I am showing day wise COUNT along with SUM of Row and SUM of Column as shown in the image below.
[image]

Here what I want is along with Total I need to show AVG as well both Row and Column wise as shown in image below

[image]

How to achieve this, I tried creating new Column and new Matrix but not getting the desired output.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no option  in Matrix for your required presentation.

Comment: @mkRabbani if not in matrix is there any other way you can suggest to achieve this

Comment: You can create individual measure for day 1 to 31 and two more measure for total and average. This way you can achieve up to column sub total/average using a table visual. Still, you can not achieve the total/average in the last 2 row in this approach :( I think better you can use 2 separate Matrix, one for total and another for average.

Comment: using Matrix, you can at best achieve this as shown in the linked image - https://imgur.com/INGUoPp This will at least get you rid from creating 31 separate measure. If this is ok with you then tell me. I will provide the full guideline.

Comment: @mkRabbani Even if I create individual Measure how to make them dynamic as day wont be constant 31, some will have 30 and some 31 and then we have Feb with 28.
and if I use 2 Matrix than in that case how to show AVG as in Matrix I can see only Total option available

Comment: Yes, that will be an issue of number of date in month. This can be solved using a calendar table. You can check the other option I have mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: @mkRabbani the matrix option that you shown seems to be helpful, can you please provide the details how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224655/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-naved-ansari).

Answer (score 0):

First, add the same value column to the **Value** field as I marked 1 and2 2 in the below image. My case, I have added the column **Sales** twice and select the **Average** calculation for the second one as shown in the image-

[image]

Now, You will get 2 column per date - **Sales** and **Average of Sales** my case. You can see only one **Average** column in the above image for date 1. This is because I have make width 0 for other columns. Apply the same for all **Average...** columns and the output will be close to your requirement.

Comment: tried implementing this but the problem is in second column I am getting AVG of entire month instead of getting AVG for that particular day. Even AVG in last column does not seems to be correct